# ImportError: No module named celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to get periodic tasks running with my Django project as per [this tutorial](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/celery-redis-django/).

However, when trying to run the Celery worker with the command below:

```
celery -A myproject worker -l info
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named celery
```

I suspect it may be because my settings files (local.py and production.py) are not as per the standard Django file structure, they are nested one folder lower.

```
├── myproject
│   ├── myproject
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── base.py
│   │   │   ├── celery.py
│   │   │   ├── local.py
│   │   │   ├── production.py
│   ├── manage.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
# myproject/myproject/settings/__init__.py

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .base import *

try:
    from .local import *
    live = False
except: 
    live = True

if live:
    from .production import *

from .celery import app as celery_app
```

**celery.py**

```
# myproject/myproject/settings/celery.py

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings.local')

app = Celery('myproject')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
  print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))



from celery.schedules import crontab
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'add-every-minute-contrab': {
        'task': 'fetch_news',
        'schedule': crontab()
    }
}
```

Celery is definitely installed.

I've looked at a lot of other threads about this error and none of them have helped. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to fix by adding the following to `__init__.py` in the directory above.

```
# myproject/myproject/__init__.py

from __future__ import absolute_import

from myproject.settings.celery import app as celery_app
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running this using the right virtual environment. In my case, I was using a different one that had been running a different project.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you use?:

```
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

You are trying to import module from the same folder #myproject/myproject/settings/
Use instead:

```
 from celery import app as celery_app
```

Comment: Doesn't help. Using .celery does a relative import of a module from the same package. The .local and .production modules import without issue in the same __init__.py file. The tutorial also mentions to use .celery to import. Tried your suggesting just to be sure and still getting the same error.